# How not to log group of logging types (say info and debug) for a type in Log4Net?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

Say I have a class with

```
private readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClassName));
```

And I want to make it not to write into log info and debug messages for **only this class type**. How shall I configure Log4Net to make it do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the log4net.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
    </root>
    <logger name="MyClassName">
        <level value="ERROR" />
   </logger>
</log4net>
```

This will set all loggers in the whole application to Debug level, except for MyClassName, which is set to Error level.